# Let users input create object

Tags: java, class, object, points

I'm writing this program where the user takes a math test. The problem Im now facing and have been trying to fix is how to display the final score at the end of the test.

I have a counter and the score increments for every correct answer, but how do I (at the end) display the final/total score? Any help is appreciated.

This is one of three classes btw.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Questions {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int answer = 0;
int point = 0;
String correct = "Correct";

public void pointers(){     
    point++;
    System.out.println(point + " point added to total score");
}

public void totalPoints(){
    pointers();
}

public void showQuestions(){

        System.out.println("\n--------------\nQuestion #1: 1+1 = ? ");
        answer = scan.nextInt();

        if(answer == 2){
           System.out.println(correct);
           pointers(); 
       }else{
           System.out.println("Wrong!");
       }

        System.out.println("\nQuestion #2: 340-23 = ? ");
        answer = scan.nextInt();
           if(answer == 317){
                  System.out.println("Correct!");
                  pointers(); 
           }else{
               System.out.println("Wrong!");
           }

        System.out.println("\nQuestion #3: 900/3 = ? ");
        answer = scan.nextInt();
           if(answer == 300){
               System.out.println("Correct!");
               pointers(); 
           }else{
               System.out.println("Wrong!");
           }

        System.out.println("\nQuestion #4: 23*2 = ? ");
        answer = scan.nextInt();
           if(answer == 46){
               System.out.println("Correct!");
               pointers(); 
           }else{
               System.out.println("Wrong!");
           }

        System.out.println("\nQuestion #5: -4+6 = ? ");
        answer = scan.nextInt();
           if(answer == 2){
               System.out.println("Correct!");
               pointers(); 
           }else{
               System.out.println("Wrong!");
           }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to get the input first and then you're asking for the age. When you type keyboard.nextInt() it is expecting an input immediately. So the problem is here:

```
    *int age = keyboard.nextInt();
    * System.out.println("Age: " + age);
    *age = keyboard.nextInt();
```

My suggestion is to just remove the first keyboard.nextInt(): 
Example: 
        System.out.println("\nName: " + name);
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

```
    System.out.println("Age: " + age);
    final int age = keyboard.nextInt();
```

and that's about it. Just be careful where you place your method calls, e.g. they should be after your println()'s.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you try to achieve, but

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello, it is time to take a math test.\nFirst we need you to enter some information about yourself.");

    System.out.print("\nEnter name: ");
    final String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
    final int age = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.close();
    System.out.println("Your personal information: " + name + " of " + age + " years old.");
}
```

}

output:

```
C:\Temp\123431>java -classpath .;Main.class Main
Hello, it is time to take a math test.
First we need you to enter some information about yourself.

Enter name: ttt
Enter Age: 321
Your personal information: ttt of 321 years old.
C:\Temp\123431>java -classpath .;Main.class Main
```